# NSTextField (inside NSTableView) NULL Placeholder showing on empty string

Tags: nstableview, placeholder, nstextfield

So I have a NSTextField, which is bound to the objectValue of the NSTableCellView. I'm filling in the table (view based NSTableView) using NSTableViewDataSource via:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject?
```

I've put a NULL Placeholder (for example "NULL") which is showing in both cases: when I return **nil** and when I return **""** (empty string) as objectValue.

There is no value transformer, nothing but a straight forward approach - simple data source based filling of the table and the text field is bound to the object value of the NSTableCellView (Table Cell View) in IB. The table is populated from array of Strings. The text field is editable.

What I'm expecting is the Placeholder to appear only when the value is **nil**. Please advise ... maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Is there a value transformer on the binding? Is the text field editable? I know that an editable `NSTextField` will set its bound key path to `nil` (and not the empty string) if the user clears its content to be empty. What you're seeing may be related to that.

Comment: Added some additional explanations to the question. 10x.

Comment: Just want to say that I have a work around - to remove the null placeholder from the binding and to set it programmatically during execution of the delegate method `func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?` if the value is nil. The problem is that this issue is .... well .... I want to understand why is this happening.

Comment: Try to find a way to check the cell view's `objectValue` at some point after things are up and showing. I suspect the text field is changing it to `nil`. You could also try temporarily making the text field non-editable just to see if the problem still happens.

Comment: objectValue checked - it's nil or empty string based on what I set (exactly as it should be). Setting the text field's behaviour  to editable, selectable or none is making no difference

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce this in a simple sample, XIB-based project. I just added a method `-foo` to my app delegate that returns `@""`. Then I added a label to the main window and bound its value binding to the app delegate's `foo` property. I set the binding's Null Placeholder to "NULL". Build and run and it shows "NULL".

Comment: Exactly. In my opinion this behaviour should be controlled somehow via NSTextFieldCell - to show NULL placeholder when value is nil or empty string, or only when it's nil. Anyway it will be nice if someone having experience with this to share some knowledge ;-)